Karatsuba algorithm for very large integers in C
I've implemented the recursive karatsuba alogrithm in C.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long long karatsuba(long long, long long);
long long findn(long long);  

long long main() {
    long long x = 1234, y = 1234;
    long long result;

    result = karatsuba(x,y);

    printf("%lld * %lld = %lld\n", x, y, result);
    
}

long long karatsuba(long long x, long long y) {
 
    int n = fmax(findn(x), findn(y));   
    int n2 = floor(n/2);
    
    if ( n == 1 )  return x * y; 

    long long a = x / pow(10, n2); 
    long long b = x % (long long) pow(10, n2); 
    long long c = y / pow(10, n2); 
    long long d = y % (long long) pow(10, n2);  
    long long p = a + b;  
    long long q = c + d;  

    long long ac = karatsuba(a, c);
    long long bd = karatsuba(b, d);
    long long pq = karatsuba(p, q);

    long long adbc = pq - ac - bd; 
    
    long long result = (long long) pow(10, n2*2) * ac + (long long) pow(10, n2) * adbc + bd;   
    return result;

} 

long long findn(long long x) {
    long long n = 1;

    while ( x/10 >= 1 ) {
        ++n;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return n;
} 

The book I'm studying from proposes as a challenge to make the algorithm work with numbers such as 3141592653589732384626433832795028841977169399375105820974944592.
We know C doesn't have a type capable of storing such numbers, let alone the result of the multiplication between two such numbers, so we must use arrays.
I've already written two functions for multiplying and adding two int [] returning a int *, but at this point i am confused on how to continue.
I was thinking about modify the karatsuba in
int *karatsuba(//parameters)
so i could return an array, which i would initialize with malloc() inside the called function for adding or multiply; by doing this the base would look something like this
if (n == 1) {//case of 1 element array
    int *res = multiply(arr1, arr2);
    return res;
}

Do you think the approach is correct?

Yes, this is a workable approach. Don't forget to free() your malloc()ated arrays once you are done with them (but not before).

All those divisions are going to make it slow. Unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise, it would be best to use a base of some power of 2. n/2 is already an integer in c so you don't need floor. Where's the array? If you multiply two long longs, you get twice the long long size for the result.

You shouldn't be using floating point arithmetic for an integer problem.  Specifically, you shouldn't be calling pow.  It will be slow, and there's always a risk that the result won't be exact.

Just start on this, so you get an idea of what's needed. When you have working code, you can submit it for review to codereview.stackexchange.com, make sure to read their site guidelines first though.

@ Tom Karzes, yes, i remember reading something like that, i'll look into it. You think it's best to write my own loop?

@Simon Goater, you mean using binary division?

I would use an array of unsigned 32-bit values, so that partial products can be handled with 64-bit. If the radix is 2^32 that makes the modulus easy. If the radix is 10^9 that makes conversion back to decimal easy, but slower calculations.

@Weather Vane, could you provide an example?

Sorry, I have my own bigint recursive solution for one problem, perhaps you should use a bigint library

@Talete Suggest you add algorithm ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm
